# Проблема со вторым JFrame

Tags: java, swing

По нажатию кнопки должен создаваться экземпляр класса `Adder`, который создает новый объект `JFrame` поверх первого, но добавлении в него элементов при помощи `GridBagConstraints` выкидывает `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container` и закрывает программу.

```
public class Adder {
    public Adder(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Имя");
        nameLabel.add(frame, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.9,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
        JTextField name = new JTextField();
        name.add(frame, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.9,
                GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, у вас ошибка в параметрах метода `add`. Вы пытаетесь добавить в компонент метка окно, но нужно совсем наоброт:

```
frame.getContentPane()
     .add(nameLabel, 
               new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.9,
                                      GridBagConstraints.NORTH, 
                                      GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
                                      new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2), 0, 0));
```